# No workspace after running jmeter tests on a Jenkins EC2 slave

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter

We use jenkins on EC2 slaves. jmeter is invoked by maven. Once jmeter job has finished, the workspace is not copied back to jenkins. We are not sure what is means to work, but our initial thought was that jenkins would handle the workspace appropriately and copy jmeter results back to the master. I appreciate it's a wishy washy question. I'm looking for suggestions on what is the right/best/good way to use jmeter on throw away slaves?

Invariably, having shut down the slave we end up with this when we look at the workspace of the job.

[image: Error: no workspace]

Do I have to copy the workspace back to master? (there's a plugin for that I hear!)

Comment: Having enabled archiving for `**/*.html`, we can see the html from the tests if we follow the link in Build History.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Jenkins doesn't copy the workspaces of slaves before they go offline.

I'm not sure there's a plugin which does this, but it's conceivable.